# MySQL apply LEFT JOIN if there is any data from CURRENT DATE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data by using below query, but the problem here is that its not displaying data from `advert_customer` which is not available in `advert_abstract`. Here in the `IF` and `LEFT JOIN` condition I am thinking the over all issue is.

Here are the table structures :

**`advert_customer`**

```
+-----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
| id  | customer_id | title              | budget | registertype | active | start_date          | end_date            | web | gender | created_at          |
+-----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
| 341 |           3 | test               |  22.00 | paid         |      1 | 2018-11-15 00:00:00 | 2018-11-22 00:00:00 |   1 | all    | 2018-11-15 12:01:07 |
| 340 |           3 | demo testing       |  15.00 | paid         |      1 | 2018-11-15 00:00:00 | 2018-11-25 00:00:00 |   1 | all    | 2018-11-15 10:52:36 |
| 339 |           3 | test data          |   8.00 | paid         |      0 | 2018-11-01 00:00:00 | 2018-11-08 00:00:00 |   1 | all    | 2018-11-14 10:38:57 |
| 336 |           3 | fgdfg              |  18.00 | paid         |      0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |   1 | all    | 2018-11-13 16:56:52 |
| 335 |           3 | Demo Testing       |   7.00 | paid         |      1 | 2018-11-12 00:00:00 | 2018-11-14 00:00:00 |   0 | all    | 2018-11-12 15:22:49 |
| 334 |           3 | Demo Advertisement |  16.00 | paid         |      1 | 2018-11-12 00:00:00 | 2018-11-17 00:00:00 |   0 | female | 2018-11-12 15:02:36 |
| 333 |           3 | today ads          |  11.00 | paid         |      1 | 2018-11-11 00:00:00 | 2018-11-15 00:00:00 |   1 | male   | 2018-11-05 18:13:45 |
| 331 |         237 | testin15           |  37.00 | paid         |      0 | 2018-10-28 00:00:00 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |   0 | male   | 2018-11-04 17:14:32 |
+-----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
```

Another table `advert_abstract` :

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | advert_customer_id | customer_id | post_id | impression_count_login | click_count | amount_spent | impression_count_nonlogin | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 12 |                 41 |           3 |    NULL |                   1020 |        NULL |         0.00 |                         1 | 2018-11-15 09:52:58 | 2018-11-15 12:20:04 |
| 11 |                 32 |           3 |    NULL |                   1013 |        NULL |         0.00 |                         1 | 2018-11-15 09:50:01 | 2018-11-15 12:20:04 |
| 10 |                 12 |           3 |    NULL |                     20 |        NULL |         0.00 |                        15 | 2018-11-14 12:49:47 | 2018-11-14 12:49:47 |
|  9 |                111 |           3 |    NULL |                     20 |        NULL |         0.00 |                      NULL | 2018-11-14 12:38:53 | 2018-11-14 12:38:53 |
|  8 |                111 |           3 |    NULL |                     10 |        NULL |         0.00 |                      NULL | 2018-11-14 12:38:36 | 2018-11-14 12:38:36 |
|  6 |                 41 |           3 |    NULL |                   1004 |        NULL |         0.00 |                         1 | 2018-11-14 10:05:40 | 2018-11-14 18:33:01 |
|  5 |                 32 |           3 |    NULL |                   1005 |        NULL |         0.00 |                         1 | 2018-11-14 10:05:26 | 2018-11-14 18:33:01 |
|  4 |                333 |           3 |    NULL |                     15 |        NULL |         0.00 |                         1 | 2018-11-14 10:05:26 | 2018-11-14 10:44:01 |
+----+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Issue is on placing left join if there is any row in the JOIN from `advert_abstract` this table then it should return the data otherwise it will be NULL for those columns.

```
select `eac`.`id`, `eac`.`gender`, `eac`.`start_date`, `eac`.`end_date`, `eac`.`ad_image_path`, `eac`.`ad_link`, `eac`.`requestfrom`, `eac`.`traffic`, `eac`.`position`, `eac`.`registertype`, `eacr`.`region_id`, `eac`.`active`, `eac`.`impression`, `eac`.`center_image_path`, `eac`.`bottom_image_path`, `eac`.`approved_by`, `er`.`name` as `country_name`, `eac`.`budget`, sum(budget/ (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)) * 1000) as daily_imp,`eaa`.`impression_count_login`,`eaa`.`impression_count_nonlogin`,sum(impression_count_login + impression_count_nonlogin) as impression_count , `eac`.`customer_id`, `eaa`.`created_at`,`eac`.`web` 

from `advert_customer` as `eac` 

inner join `advert_customer_regions` as `eacr` on `eac`.`id` = `eacr`.`advert_customer_id` 

inner join `regions` as `er` on `er`.`id` = `eacr`.`region_id`                                  

left join `advert_abstract` as `eaa` on `eac`.`id` =`eaa`.`advert_customer_id`             <<<<<<<-----------------------    I WANT THIS TO HAPPEN IF THERE IS ANY ROW IN THE TABLE FROM CURENT DATE

  where `er`.`name` = 'India' and 
        `eac`.`web` = 1 and
        `eac`.`registertype` = 'paid' and
        `eac`.`active` = 1 and 
        `eac`.`approved_by` = 1 and 
        `eac`.`gender` = 'all' and 
        DATE(eac.start_date) <= DATE(CURDATE()) and
        DATE(eac.end_date) >=   DATE(CURDATE()) and

IF((SELECT CASE WHEN DATE(eaa.created_at) = DATE(CURDATE()) THEN eaa.created_at ELSE NULL END), eaa.created_at , NULL)                  <<<<<<<-----------------------    ON THIS LINE I THINK THE ISSUE IS

group by `eac`.`id`, `eac`.`gender`, `eac`.`start_date`, `eac`.`end_date`, `eac`.`ad_image_path`, `eac`.`ad_link`, `eac`.`requestfrom`, `eac`.`traffic`, `eac`.`position`, `eac`.`registertype`, `eacr`.`region_id`, `eac`.`active`, `eac`.`impression`, `eac`.`center_image_path`, `eac`.`bottom_image_path`, `eac`.`approved_by`, `eac`.`budget`, `eac`.`customer_id`, `eac`.`web`
                                       HAVING impression_count < daily_imp
                                        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
```

I am not sure if how can I write the `IF` AND `LEFT JOIN` condition or is there any other JOIN method I should try to fetch data from. So that I can get all the data if the data is not available in `advert_abstract` then also I result out rest of the details.

Any suggestions will be helpful, thank you (in advance)!

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: `IF(SELECT..` does not look right in your `WHERE` condition(s). A relevant and minimal sample data will be helpful in reformulating the query in a proper (and possibly, performant) manner.

Comment: Sure I will try to share some data sample as well.

Comment: It would be best if you can set it up in https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Ok I try creating a database on db-fiddle.com but it was taking my queries not sure why. So here I am trying to help with the database structure attached in the question and hit added with `<<<<<<-----------` in query

Comment: see:  https://rextester.com/VKN74657   there are 4 tables in your query, but you only provide data for two, and even then there are many columns referenced in the query that don't exist in your samples above. If attempting an MCVE you should aim to provide all the data needed - or reduce the query scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really saying what you want to achieve. So I can only guess ... but here is a suggestion:

```
select `eac`.`id`, `eac`.`gender`, `eac`.`start_date`, `eac`.`end_date`, 
`eac`.`ad_image_path`, `eac`.`ad_link`, `eac`.`requestfrom`, 
`eac`.`traffic`, `eac`.`position`, `eac`.`registertype`, `eacr`.`region_id`, 
`eac`.`active`, `eac`.`impression`, `eac`.`center_image_path`, 
`eac`.`bottom_image_path`, `eac`.`approved_by`, `er`.`name` as `country_name`, 
`eac`.`budget`, 
sum(budget/ (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)) * 1000) as daily_imp,  
`eaa`.`impression_count_login`,`eaa`.`impression_count_nonlogin`,
sum(impression_count_login + impression_count_nonlogin) as impression_count , 
`eac`.`customer_id`, 
CASE WHEN `eaa`.`created_at` = DATE(CURDATE())  THEN DATE(CURDATE())
     WHEN `eaa`.`created_at` IS NULL            THEN NULL
     ELSE NULL
END AS created_at,
`eac`.`web` 

from `advert_customer` as `eac` 

inner join `advert_customer_regions` as `eacr` on `eac`.`id` = 
`eacr`.`advert_customer_id` 

inner join `regions` as `er` on `er`.`id` = `eacr`.`region_id`                                  

left join `advert_abstract` as `eaa` on `eac`.`id` =`eaa`.`advert_customer_id`         

 where `er`.`name` = 'India' and 
    `eac`.`web` = 1 and
    `eac`.`registertype` = 'paid' and
    `eac`.`active` = 1 and 
    `eac`.`approved_by` = 1 and 
    `eac`.`gender` = 'all' and 
    DATE(eac.start_date) <= DATE(CURDATE()) and
    DATE(eac.end_date)   >=   DATE(CURDATE())            

group by `eac`.`id`, `eac`.`gender`, `eac`.`start_date`, `eac`.`end_date`, 
`eac`.`ad_image_path`, `eac`.`ad_link`, `eac`.`requestfrom`, `eac`.`traffic`, 
`eac`.`position`, `eac`.`registertype`, `eacr`.`region_id`, `eac`.`active`, 
`eac`.`impression`, `eac`.`center_image_path`, `eac`.`bottom_image_path`, 
`eac`.`approved_by`, `eac`.`budget`, `eac`.`customer_id`, `eac`.`web`
                                   HAVING impression_count < daily_imp
                                    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
```

So what does it do?
It implements a correct left join with table `advert_abstract` so data from `advert_customer` are displayed even if there are no data available in `advert_abstract`.
Secondly it only displays the "created_at" date if it exists and if it is equal to the current date. Otherwise null is returned for that field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to include a "join condition". In other words, place the wanted filter directly into the join, and do NOT include in in the where clause. This way the left join will only include rows from that table which meet that criteria

```
SELECT
    eac.id, eac.gender, eac.start_date, eac.end_date, eac.ad_image_path
  , eac.ad_link, eac.requestfrom, eac.traffic, eac.position, eac.registertype
  , eacr.region_id, eac.active, eac.impression, eac.center_image_path
  , eac.bottom_image_path, eac.approved_by, er.name AS country_name, eac.budget
  , eaa.impression_count_login, eaa.impression_count_nonlogin
  , eac.customer_id, eaa.created_at, eac.web
  , SUM (budget / (DATEDIFF (end_date, START_DATE)) * 1000) AS daily_imp
  , SUM (impression_count_login + impression_count_nonlogin) AS impression_count
FROM advert_customer AS eac
INNER JOIN advert_customer_regions AS eacr ON eac.id = eacr.advert_customer_id
INNER JOIN regions AS er ON er.id = eacr.region_id

   # I WANT THIS TO HAPPEN IF THERE IS ANY ROW IN THE TABLE FROM CURRENT DATE 
LEFT JOIN advert_abstract AS eaa ON eac.id = eaa.advert_customer_id 
                                AND DATE(eaa.created_at) = CURDATE()

WHERE er.name = 'India'
AND eac.web = 1
AND eac.registertype = 'paid'
AND eac.active = 1
AND eac.approved_by = 1
AND eac.gender = 'all'
AND CURDATE() BETWEEN eac.start_date AND eac.end_date
GROUP BY
    eac.id, eac.gender, eac.start_date, eac.end_date, eac.ad_image_path
  , eac.ad_link, eac.requestfrom, eac.traffic, eac.position, eac.registertype
  , eacr.region_id, eac.active, eac.impression, eac.center_image_path
  , eac.bottom_image_path, eac.approved_by, er.name, eac.budget
  , eaa.impression_count_login, eaa.impression_count_nonlogin
  , eac.customer_id, eaa.created_at, eac.web
```

Please note you do not need to use `date(curdate())` because `curdate()` is just a date. I have also suggested using between in the query above, I think it is easier to comprehend.

There are some column aliases missing in these lines, see `???.`

```
, SUM (???.budget / (DATEDIFF (???.end_date, ???.START_DATE)) * 1000) AS daily_imp
, SUM (???.impression_count_login + ???.impression_count_nonlogin) AS impression_count
```

It is important to reference ALL columns with their appropriate alias.